# VB6 RTF to Word 2010

Tags: vb6, ms-word, export, rtf

I have a VB6 application which has RTF field that eventually gets copied and pasted to Word 2010 document.

Texts and pictures get pasted all nicely except when a chart element is pasted, it has axis labels hidden by default.
So I basically have to click individual chart and "show" axis labels.

Is there any way to make it visible by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to expand on your question a bit for more specific details but it is possible using OLE Automation to manipulate the objects in your Word document from VB6. Here's a better sample than I could give you from memory: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237337

Comment: Basically, I wish to make charts' axis tick label be visible by default when it is exported to Word 2010. Currently, it has to be manually turned on by clicking on the chart in Word -> Chart Tools -> Axes -> Primary Horizontal Axis -> Show Left to Right Axis. Same for the Y Axis.

Comment: You can record a macro and then use that as the basis for your OLE Automation code